# Install oozie sharelib

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie

I want to install oozie sharelib to HDFS as part of test setup without building oozie package. I couldn't find oozie-sharelib.tar.gz in any of thre repository.

Any idea if it can be done without downloading/building oozie?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oozie sharelib is bundled with oozie.

You must download/install oozie.

It will be in the $OOZIE_HOME folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sharelib is required jar files for various operations under oozie environment, which get created with the successful build of oozie. it is possible without build of oozie, you can create share/lib folder inside hdfs and put required jars inside it and when you need them you can always provide a path of share lib.
P.S. this is not recommended so if possible try to build using oozie.

Answer (score -1):

As every one mention its not recommended, but if you want to get SharedLib Dump you have to download the same from the Oozie Site of respected Oozie Verions, as the ShareLib zip dump comes with Oozie Bundle only.

Alternet you can create the Oozie SharedLib Manually but getting list of Jars from respected Lib Locatino, which use to be available in ShareLIb Location and create the SharedLib manually in Hadoop Location with "User:Group" as "oozie:hadoop" as SharedLib should be install and Configure with "oozie:hadoop only" snapshot
[image]

[Referece URL](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie/) will help you to know which all JAR required to available in SharedLib