# Shared lib size vary between HDP 2.3.2.0-2950 and HDP 2.3.0.0-2557

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

We have installed HDP on two different boxes with version HDP 2.3.2.0-2950 and HDP-2.3.0.0-2557. It seems that there are lot of JAR files are missing in oozie shared lib in 2.3.0.0-2557 version.

On version HDP 2.3.2.0-2950 - we are getting following size

```
-r--r--r--. 1 root      root   338855497 Oct  1 02:23 oozie-sharelib.tar.gz
```

And on version HDP-2.3.0.0-2557 - we are getting following size

```
-r--r--r--. 1 root  root   226634871 Jul 14 20:39 oozie-sharelib.tar.gz
```

Because of missing JAR, we are not able to successfully run oozie job on `2.3.0.0-2557`.

Answer (score 0):

It will be bit difficult to figure it out which all the Jar's are missing, without checking Oozie Logs.
So if you want to place all the Jars in SharedLib manually, you have to check the Find Output List of Jar's required for Oozie SharedLib, which can be listed out  with the URL from 
[Install oozie sharelib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901760/install-oozie-sharelib/34586033#34586033)

Just Collect the List of Jar's and build SharedLib which supports your Hadoop & Oozie Version, and place the same in HDFS and check the status

Hope These will help .